# Why Node.js worker message listener prints first then the other console

Tags: node.js, multithreading, worker, node-worker-threads

This code runs two times, once on the main thread and the worker thread.

```js
const {isMainThread, Worker, parentPort} = require('worker_threads')
console.log(`isMainThread: ${isMainThread}`);

if(isMainThread) {
    console.log('from main thread');
    const worker  = new Worker(__filename);
    worker.on('message', (message)=>{
        console.log(`message for Worker: ${message}`);
    });
    worker.on('error', (e)=>{
        console.log('error');
    });
    worker.on('exit', (code) => {
        console.log(code);
    });
} else {
    // case 1:
    console.log('from worker thread');
    process.exit();
    
    // case 2:
    console.log('from worker thread');
    parentPort.postMessage('hi worker!');
}
```

Output Case 1:

```
isMainThread: true
from main thread
isMainThread: false
0
```

Why does console.log, not execute from else?

Output Case 2:

```
isMainThread: true
from main thread
isMainThread: false
message for Worker: hi worker!
from worker thread
0
```

How worker "message" listener most of the time execute the log first?
despite the postMessage is called after log every time.